# How to only show the last 20 results from an updating/real time graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, animation, graph

I've got this script running to update every time a new value is added to my csv file (it's a manual log taking in values from a machine):

```
from itertools import count
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

x_vals = []
y_vals = []

counter=0
index = count()


def animate(i):
    data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Owner/Downloads/Manual-Log-27Nov2020-150846.csv')
    data=data.dropna()
    data['Date And Time']=data['Date']+' '+data['Time']
    Date = data['Date And Time']
    Temp = data['Temperature']
    Pressure = data['Pressure']
    pH = data['pH']
    
        
    plt.cla()

    plt.plot(Date, Temp, label='Temperature')
    plt.plot(Date, Pressure, label='Pressure')
    plt.plot(Date, pH, label='pH')
    
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.xlabel('Date and Time')
    plt.ylabel('Y Values')
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    
    plt.tight_layout()


ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=30000)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Since it's such a large file (20k lines or so) the resulting graph is huge and you can't really read the data properly. Is there a way I could only get it to show the 20 most recent readings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can slice it or get first n records. you can apply the following after your code line : data=data.dropna()

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Count':[2,33,4,6,8,9],'apha':['A','B','C','D','E','F']})
df_sorted=sorted_df = df.sort_values(by=['Count'], ascending=True) # in case needed
df_limited=df_sorted.head(3) # this is one you are looking for
```

Comment: Thanks for this! This gave me an idea to just use .tail() after, so it now just runs like this: 

```
data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Owner/Downloads/Manual-Log-27Nov2020-150846.csv')
    data=data.dropna()
    
    data=pd.DataFrame(data)

    data=data.tail(25)
```